# Can I copy two profiles on reinstallation

Tags: email, thunderbird

I have just lost my twin boot Windows and Ubuntu system which after some fun have now restored. Before creating my new profile in Thunderbird, I have read how to transfer my old profile in, but I cannot see whether I can install my old profile and ADD emails from a previous Windows 7 profile. Within the email folder there is a email file containing the emails. Is it possible to copy and paste these into the other email file within the Mail folder?

Answer (score 1):

Mails in Thunderbird are stored in mbox formatted files in your user profile. These mbox files are text files formatted in a special way, and they have *no* file extension.

You could copy the relevant mail files from your Windows installation, rename them with a name not yet existing in your Thunderbird account under Linux, and move them there. In Thunderbird, they will show up as new folders that have the name you gave to the mbox file. You can access and organize that mail in these folders.

This makes sense for locally stored mail only. For IMAP mail, just connect to the server to retrieve the mail stored on the server.

Local mail is stored under `/home/<yourlogin>/.thunderbird/<random string>.default-release/Mail/Local Folders`. Unnamed files with the names of your folders are the mbox files. They are accompagnied by a similarly named `.msf` file. This is an index file that automatically will be recreated by Thunderbird if it does not exist. Thus, there is no need to copy these.